# Assert that all the items in a list satisfy a condition in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, assert

I need your help. I'm writing a code to merge two sorted arrays into one sorted array.
The problem is I don't know how to put the condition for the input.

```
def merge_and_sort (A,B):
    # condition that A and B are already sorted
   necessary step
   return result
```

For example, A=[1, 2, 4, 10, 20] and B=[2, 4, 4.5, 10, 100] would be acceptable; but A=[1, 2, 4, 10, 20] and B=[2, 4, 4.5, 100, 10] would not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use sorted(list) on both entries and then concatenate them.

Comment: `if A == sorted(A) and B == sorted(B):`

Answer (score 0):

check if number in the list is less than the next number.

Code:

```
def is_sorted(L):
    return all([ L[i] <= L[i+1] for i in range(len(L)-1)])
    
A=[1, 2, 4, 10, 20] 
B=[2, 4, 4.5, 100, 10]
B1=[2, 4, 4.5, 10, 100]

print('A is', ('not sorted', 'sorted')[is_sorted(A)])
print('B is', ('not sorted', 'sorted')[is_sorted(B)])
print('B1 is', ('not sorted', 'sorted')[is_sorted(B1)])
print('A and B are', ('not sorted', 'already sorted')[is_sorted(A) and is_sorted(B)])
print('A and B1 are', ('not sorted', 'already sorted')[is_sorted(A) and is_sorted(B1)])
```

Output:

```
A is sorted
B is not sorted
B1 is sorted
A and B are not sorted
A and B1 are already sorted
```

Comment: Use a generator expression with `all` to take advantage of short-circuiting and to not require linear space: `all( L[i] <= L[i+1] for i in range(len(L)-1) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_and_sort (A,B):
    # maiking a varibale to check if both list are sorted
    both_sorted = False
    
    # comparing a orignal listed with a sorted on to check if 
    # its already sorted or not 
    
    if A == sorted(A) and B == sorted(B):
        both_sorted = True

    #This list will contain both the list
    result  = []
    
    #if both lists are sorted put list A in result
    # and then list B
    if both_sorted == True:
        print("Both list accepted")
        for i in A:
            result.append(i)
        for i in B:
            result.append(i) 

        result.sort()


    
    
    else:
        print("Lists are not sorted")           
    return result


A = [1, 2, 4, 10, 20] 
B = [2, 4, 4.5, 10, 100] 

res = merge_and_sort(A,B)
print(res)
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the teacher will start yelling when they get to the `result.sort()` line. I think OP is supposed to write a function that merges the elements of A and the elements of B into a sorted list.